# Is this a subjective question?

Tags: support, subjective

Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7013155/should-tostring-be-used-for-critical-information) a subjective question?

I also have lots of similar questions but I refrain to ask them on SO because of the **subjective** rule. If senior members of SO can confidently confirm this question as not subjective, then I will ask similar questions of this nature.

Comment: I think this particular question is okay. But that shouldn't be interpreted as saying that any subjective question is okay. You'd have to share with us some of the questions that you'd like to ask in order to get the community's opinion.

Answer (score 5):

It was upvoted 5 times with zero close votes.  So I believe the community does not think it is too subjective.  It does not resemble a "What is the 'best' way to X?' type of question, instead it is asking if there are any best practices for a specific situation.

For your question, just make sure you eliminate the subjectivity where you can.

Also check out:

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/